# WCF security configuration and IIS settings

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7

I'm new to WCF and IIS.

Suppose I set up a WCF service with wsHttpBinding and Message Security and Windows authentication. Does that mean I don't need to use https on my IIS server? Ie. Is the message secure or isn't it?

Let me know if there is any further information I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the message is secure as it will be encrypted and signed by WCF in case of Message security. But make sure you considered all disadvantages of massage security. The most significant are: 1. Poor interoperability. 2. Worse performance compared to transport security.

For more details please refer to this article [Message and Transport Security](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Ch%2007%20-%20Message%20and%20Transport%20Security%20in%20WCF)
You will also find the scenarios where it is best to use message security.

Answer (score 1):

start with transport and message security understanding. We will then see simple code samples of how to implement transport and message security using WsHTTP bindings. We will also see the differences between ‘BasicHttpBinding’ and ‘WsHttpBinding’ with the help of a simple code. WCF security is a huge topic by itself, but I am sure with this article you will get a quick start of how to go about WCF security

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36732/WCF-FAQ-Part-3-10-security-related-FAQ